# Recordset.RecordCount not allowed

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2, ado

I want to get the record count from a result set when querying SQL Server 2008 R2 from ASP VBscript:

```
Conn = "Provider=SQLNCLI10; DataTypeCompatibility=80; Data Source=Source; Initial Catalog=catalog; User ID=id; Password=pw; Network Library=dbmssocn; Encrypt=Yes;"
```

This returns the correct record count:

```
consulta = "select 'x' x;"

rs.open consulta, Conexao, 3
Response.Write(rs.RecordCount)
```

But when I select from a temporary table it throws an error:

```
consulta = "select 'x' x into #t; select * from #t; drop table #t;"

rs.open consulta, Conexao, 3
Response.Write(rs.RecordCount)

ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'

Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use `.NextRecordSet()`:

```vbs
strsql = "select 'x' x into #t; select * from #t; drop table #t;"

rs.Open strsql, conn

'Move to your 2nd recordset to return the values (in this case 'x')
Set rs = rs.NextRecordset()
if not rs.eof then
    response.write rs(0)
end if
rs.close
```

This also works for me if I separate the sql strings out and use `EXECUTE` or `OPEN` as needed:

```vbs
'Create Temp Table 
strsql = "select 'x' x into #t; "
conn.execute strsql

'Select From Temp Table
strsql = "select * from #t;"
rs.open strsql, conn
if not rs.eof then
    response.write rs(0)
end if
rs.close

'Drop Temp Table
strsql = "drop table #t;"
conn.execute strsql
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the provider you are using? `SQLOLEDB` or `SQLNCLI10`/`SQLNCLI11`?

Comment: @Clodoaldo -- for my testing, I am connecting to an MSSQL 2008 R2 database using SQLOLEDB.  My connection string looks like this: ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=ServerName;Database=DBName;UId=UserId;Pwd=Password" -- hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is just one of compound SQL command statements (the use of temporary tables in my example), then here's a pretty general solution:

```
Set RecSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

On Error Resume Next
Call RecSet.Open(SQLstr, ADO_ConnObj, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic)

ErrNum = Err.Number         'Capture it for later error processing
ErrDesc = Err.Description   '   "

Do While ErrNum = 0 And RecSet.State <> adStateOpen
    'SQL specifications that include use of local temporary tables (subsequently referenced by
    'a final SELECT statement) are an example of compound command statements for which ADO
    'returns a collection of record sets, one for each command statement in the specification.
    'Local temporary tables are automatically dropped when they go out of scope, resulting in
    'their corresponding record set's State property being set to adStateClosed, once the query
    'is finished executing.  So any such closed record sets must be ignored and skipped over,
    'in order to find the actual query-results data, which will usually be the last record set
    'in the collection, with a State property value of adStateOpen.  So search for the first
    'open record set:

    Set RecSet = RecSet.NextRecordset
    If RecSet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No open ADO DB Recordsets found in the returned Recordset collection."

        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop
On Error GoTo 0

'Process the actual data (or error conditions)...
```